# iphone global variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to open my SQLite database in my appDelegate class and reference that database in all my other classes that need the database.  I have tried using :
static sqlite3 *database = nil;

But when I try to reference it in my other classes with appDelegate.database, I get a compile error of "error: request for member 'database' in something not a structure or union."  How do you reference these types of properies?

Answer (score 6):

You should access any variables stored in the app Delegate through the follow general formula:

```
YourAppDelegateName *delegate = (YourAppDelegateName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
//access specific variables in delegate as follows:
sqlite3 *temp = delegate.database;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the FMDB Objective C wrapper for sqlite. It will really simplify the access to your sqlite database. You can download it from

http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/fmdb#fmdb/src

Then,

you can use the following sample code, and use a NSString *db_path variable to access your db from other classes (you use your app delegate to access db_path, then use

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
```

to acces your db. See the sample code below.

```
- (NSString *) initialize_db {
    NSString *DATABASE_RESOURCE_NAME = @"yourDbName";
    NSString *DATABASE_RESOURCE_TYPE = @"db";
    NSString *DATABASE_FILE_NAME = @"yourDbName.db";

    // copy the database from the bundle if necessary
    // look to see if DB is in known location (~/Documents/$DATABASE_FILE_NAME)
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *dbFilePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: DATABASE_FILE_NAME];
    [dbFilePath retain];

    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: dbFilePath]) {
        // didn't find db, need to copy
        NSString *backupDbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                  pathForResource:DATABASE_RESOURCE_NAME
                                  ofType:DATABASE_RESOURCE_TYPE];
        if (backupDbPath == nil) {
            // couldn't find backup db to copy, bail
            NSLog (@"couldn't init db");
            return NULL;
        } else {
            BOOL copiedBackupDb = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                   copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath
                                   toPath:dbFilePath
                                   error:nil];
            if (! copiedBackupDb) {
                // copying backup db failed, bail
                NSLog (@"couldn't init db");
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }


    return dbFilePath;

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    FMResultSet *item_rs;   


    // copy the database from the bundle if necessary
    db_path = [self initialize_db];
    if (! db_path) {
        // TODO: alert the user!
        NSLog (@"couldn't init db");
        return;
    }


    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open the db");
    }


    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from yourTable"];
    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"Err %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }

    while ([rs next]) {
        [yourArray addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"yourColumnName"]];

    }

    [rs close];  



    [db close];


    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create an instance property for the database.  My assumption that the static declaration was sufficient was incorrect.  BTW, the FMDB/ORM advice is great.  I am a huge fan of ORMs.  However, this project is my first iphone and it is a small amount of database work and I want to learn.  So, I am going to do it old school.  Thanks for the advice.

Here are the code changes I made to make my global reference work.. Hope it helps someone:

```
/* myAppDelegate.h file */
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
... // you may have windows etc here
    sqlite3 *database;

}

@property (readwrite) sqlite3 *database;


/* myAppDelegate.m file */
@implementation myAppDelegate
...
@synthesize database;

/* some method in some class that uses the database */
- (void) getSomeData
{
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *) [[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] delegate ];

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
// get the data here.
}

}
```